# Автопост в ВК по средствам CURL

Tags: php, вконтакте, curl

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться с таким вопросом, при попытке загрузить пост на стену в вк по средствам CURL(не через API VK) через ссылку на картинку,  на стену приходит ссылка  в виде текста, а не картинка как это можно исправить? Заранее спсибо за ответ.

Comment: **посредством**

Comment: А почему не API?

Comment: Во-первых, для начала таки не мешало бы объяснить, почему не API. Во-вторых, в браузере картинка крепится с помощью JS и ещё нескольких запросов к серверу, соответственно вам надо через CURL повторить их все, а не просто ссылку отправлять

Comment: Не через API потому как я нахожусь в процессе обучения и интерес представляет php curl в большей мере чем средства предоставленые для решения подобных задач от соцсети.. В обход js не получится, я правильно понял?